# QueryDSL inverting a query no longer supported in Spring Data MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

In a previous release of Spring Data MongoDB along with QueryDSL I was able perform the following.

```java
return ExpressionUtils.allOf(aggregatePredicates).not();
```

When we upgraded to Spring Boot 2 we found that we were getting the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.bson.Document cannot be cast to class java.lang.Iterable
```

Presumably, the .not() is now requiring a List (Iterable) although query DSL flattens to an object.

I am surprised to find no reference to this 'bug' (I'll call it!) even if I try a few different ways to do a NOT on a predicate I get the same error.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Which version of Spring Data MongoDB are you using. Might be related to [DATAMONGO-1943](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1943). If not, please report an issue via [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO). Thank you!